# Node.js shopping cart

Tags: node.js

Are there any good shopping cart modules/services out there that people have integrated with node.js?

The specific requirement I'm struggling with is that I'm selling prints of photographs. My application will have thousands of photos, and I don't want to setup every photo as an item in a shopping cart. I'd prefer to have a half dozen items based on the different print sizes, then essentially have the image identifier as an attribute of the product.

I might end up just coding this myself, but when I start thinking about modifying carts, calculating taxes, etc., it starts looking bigger than necessary, so if there's something I can integrate rather than building that would be great.

Answer (score 6):

Since there were no answers I thought I'd loop back and provide the solution I'm moving towards...

I've decided to use Simplecart.js (simplecartjs.org) to maintain a shopping cart on the browser. I'll maintain my product catalog and pricing in MongoDB, and push the catalog to the client so I can use Simplecart's functions there.

Since Simplecart is client-based, when the user checks out I'll reload pricing from MongoDB (to ensure no funny business on the client), process payment with Swipe.com or similar, and be off to the races. Perhaps not perfect, but saves me from doing cart management and checkout front-end.

Comment: Not exactly a Node.JS soluition, but nice suggestion! I would recommend only using the product id on the client side and serve up the product data from the server side. This information schema should be used as maybe a cache for the products. Being language agnostic, Simplecart does save a tremendous amount of time for the frontend, which is the hardest part of ecommerce. This answer now raises the question: how would I model the data and which ORM for Node.JS should I use? Thankfully, that's the easy part, in my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure your proposal for securing SimpleCart can work. Even with a price refresh during checkout, it will be relatively easy for anyone with a JS console to purchase items using their own, user-defined price.

I've not see a proposed solution that doesn't involve creating a server-side process to validate prices before committing the order and the payment transaction, which of course makes SimpleCart no-so-simple anymore.

See commentary on the SimpleCart GitHub issue tracker:

- https://github.com/wojodesign/simplecart-js/issues/329
- https://github.com/wojodesign/simplecart-js/issues/150

Comment: This is true, however I'm basically using SimpleCart solely to keep track of products and quantities, and doing all price calculations on the server. I'd agree this takes out some of the "Simple" of SimpleCart, but I'm not very good at front end so this handles the front end. I am in the process of revisiting this whole system, so hopefully there's a better solution now.